# C++ executable, vcredist errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created a simple C++ Opengl application in Visual Studio 2019 and some of my users have reported getting a vcredist related error at program start. The application folder contains just the .exe and some .dll's for libraries. Do I really need to send users the 2019 x64 vcredist .exe for them to install? is there no way to embed this into the application? How do projects like Godot do this?

Comment: Short answer: No. Slightly longer answer: Create an installer package and include the redistributable in that (or set it as a prerequisite).

Comment: See [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019) and [Deployment Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-examples?view=msvc-160).

Answer (score 0):

You can include vcredist.exe in your program. Games usually try and do this if they have there own launcher which can run and install the appropriate DLLs for this user in the background. If you have a smaller scale program you can just make a installer which checks if the user has the appropriate DLLs installed and if they don't it installs them for the user.

- [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)
- [Understanding the Dependencies of a Visual C++ Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/understanding-the-dependencies-of-a-visual-cpp-application?view=msvc-160)